# VLC streaming 'changing src onclick' javascript code can hear sound/can't see video

Tags: javascript, stream, innerhtml, vlc

I'm trying to add a vlc player (version 1.1.8, live stream, internet explorer) to my webpag and give the user the ability to change channel by clicking one of the buttons.

```
<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
id="vlcplayer" 
width="720px"
height="540px" 
classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"> 
<param name="Src" value= "udp://@239.0.10.115:1234">  
<param name="volume" value="100" />
<param name="autoplay" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="false" />
<param name="fullscreen" value="true" />
</object>
```

The code above works fine, I can hear and see the video but I don't know how to change the Src value upon click (the udp/channel).
I tried to use the code:

```
document.getElementById('vlcplayer').src = 'udp://@239.0.10.105:1234'
```

but that doesn't work as .src seems to be undefined.

Q1. Is there a way to change the src of the object? Could I get an example please?

I couldn't find a way so I resorted to create the object in javascript with the src as variable whenever a channel button is clicked:

```
uri = 'udp://@239.0.10.115:1234';
VLCPlayerObject = '<object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlcplayer" width="720px"height="540px" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"> <param name="Src" value= '+uri+'> <param name="volume" value="100" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><param name="fullscreen" value="true" /></object>'; 
document.getElementById('videoDisplayDivID').innerHTML=VLCPlayerObject;
```

The problem with this code however is that I can't see the video but I can hear it and I can hear the channel changing.

Q2. Is this some software problem or is my coding wrong? How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I attempted to make the following changes in a new test version

in the object I added an id:

```
<param name="Src" value= "udp://@239.0.10.112:1234">
```

was changed to

```
<param name="Src" value= "udp://@239.0.10.112:1234" id ="videoSrc">
```

and then in the javascript code:

```
var temp = document.getElementById("videoSrc").getAttribute("value");
alert("old udp: " + temp);

var sourceParameter= document.getElementById("videoSrc");
sourceParameter.setAttribute("value", "udp://@239.0.10.115:1234");

var temp2 = document.getElementById("videoSrc").getAttribute("value");
alert("new udp: " + temp2);
```

This code does display the udp and it shows that the udp does change after the function is run. HOWEVER although the udp changes the video doesn't actually switch to that channel for some reason. (I've checked that the channels are different)

Q3. How do I get the video to update as well?

**ANSWERED**

Added an item to the playlist (the original src value gets set as playlist item 0 btw)

```
var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcplayer");
vlc.playlist.add("udp://@239.0.10.115:1234");
vlc.playlist.playItem(1);
```

Now I just have to properly code it to work for every channel.

Comment: That's not really how plugins have to work – they're not obliged to watch the DOM for changes. The <param> tags are to provide initialisation values to the plugin; to do anything after initialisation, you need to use some sort of plugin–specific API. VLC's is documented here: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin#Javascript_API_description (This is part of the reason why the "walled garden" approach of plugins is terrible.)

Comment: Looking at the API docs, my approach would be to add channel URLs to the plugin's playlist, remember the numbers, then just switch in the playlist when the button is clicked.

Comment: F YES! Thank you! I added var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcplayer");
  vlc.playlist.add("udp://@239.0.10.115:1234");
  vlc.playlist.playItem(1); and it works!

Comment: I wouldn't hardcode the `1`. `add()` returns the number of the item you just added, use that.

Comment: yeah yeah that was just for testing